# ¿Cuál es mi error en este algortimo?

Tags: algoritmos, busqueda, vectores, pseudocódigo, sl

El ejercicio es el siguiente:

Generar un vector con valores enteros aleatorios de N posiciones (se debe leer
N por teclado) y buscar si un elemento K se encuentra repetido en el vector
(puede asumir por ejemplo que los valores aleatorios tomaran valores entre 0 –
100 o cualquier otro rango que usted desee utilizar).

Yo estoy programando en pseudocódigo, en un lenguaje llamado SL de CNC, también utilizo PSeInt. Ya he intentado saber cuál es mi problema, pero necesito una ayuda y opinión para este ejercicio.

¿Cuál es mi error en este ejercicio?

```
const
    N = 27
var
    arreglo : vector[N] numerico
    i, k : numerico
    encontrado : logico
inicio 
    cls()

    i = 1

    mientras (i <= N)
    {
        arreglo[i] = random(100)
        i = i + 1
    }

    i = 1

    desde i = 1 hasta N
    {
        imprimir (arreglo[i])
        imprimir (" ")
    }

    imprimir("\n")

    imprimir("Escriba el numero que se repite: ")
    leer(k)

    i = 1
    encontrado = FALSE

    mientras (i <= N)
    {
        si(arreglo[i] == k)
        {
         encontrado = TRUE
        }
        i = i + 1
    }

    si (encontrado)
    {
        imprimir ("\n Elemento ", k, " se repite en el vector")
    sino
        imprimir ("\n Elemento no se repite en el vector ")
    }
fin
```

Comment: Cual seria el problema? tu algoritmo debe devolver verdadero si el elemento a buscar aparece al menos 2 veces?

Comment: Sólo estás verificando que `k` exista en el arreglo. En ninguna parte compruebas su repetición

Comment: Puedes declarar la variable `encontrado` como numérica `0` y cada vez que aparece `k` en el arreglo le sumas uno, seguido compruebas si vale `2` y presentas el mensaje correspondiente, etc.

Comment: Como compruebo que **k** se repite y puedo mandarle un mensaje al usuario de que se repite? @ffflabs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El error es que no estás incrementando en una variable el valor una vez encontrado el valor que se repite.
Lo que estás haciendo es buscar un elemento en un vector y decir si el elemento está en el vector, pero no si se repite.
Para hacer lo que estás pidiendo es necesario crear una variable, que se puede llamar `numero_repeticiones`, y allí ir almacenado la cantidad de elementos que se repite un elemento en el vector si es que lo hace.
Después al final preguntar si el número de repeticiones es mayor a 1 (se repite) y en tal caso mostrar al usuario que se repite, de lo contrario informar que no se repite o que no está en el vector

Con estas modificaciones la variable `encontrado` ya no es necesaria, ya que basta chequear el número de repeticiones para determinar si el número está o no en el arreglo, por lo que esta variable se remueve del programa.

El programa quedaría así:

```
const
    N = 27
var
    arreglo : vector[N] numerico
    i, k : numerico
    numero_repeticiones : numerico
inicio 
    cls()

    numero_repeticiones = 0

    i = 1

    mientras (i <= N)
    {
        arreglo[i] = random(100)
        i = i + 1
    }

    i = 1

    desde i = 1 hasta N
    {
        imprimir (arreglo[i])
        imprimir (" ")
    }

    imprimir("\n")

    imprimir("Escriba el numero a buscar: ")
    leer(k)

    i = 1

    mientras (i <= N)
    {
        si(arreglo[i] == k)
        {
            numero_repeticiones = numero_repeticiones + 1
        }
        i = i + 1
    }

    si (numero_repeticiones == 0) { //no esta en el vector
        imprimir ("\n Elemento no está en el vector ")
    sino 
        si (numero_repeticiones == 1) { //esta pero no se repite 
            imprimir ("\n Elemento no se repite en el vector ")
        sino //se repite numero_repeticiones
            imprimir ("\n Elemento ", k, " se repite en el vector")
        }
    }
fin
```

Comment: Ahora es otra cosa!!!! pero igual, la variable encontrado no tiene nada de sentido, alcanza con verificar cuanto vale numero de repeticiones...

Comment: basta con controlar si numero_repeticiones es 0, o 1, o mas ;)

Comment: La variable encontrado si tiene sentido, para saber si el elemento está o no en el vector, pues puede darse el caso de que el elemento que ingrese el usuario no esté en el vector.

Comment: y en ese caso, numero_repeticiones se quedara en cero ;)... no, no tiene sentido

Comment: no se repite, pero puede que esté una vez en el vector

Comment: entonces numero_repeticiones te va a dar 1 ;)

Comment: si (numero_repeticiones = 0) {no esta] sino {si numero_repeticiones = 1 {esta pero no se repite} sino {se repite numero_repeticiones} }